# Access session variable in jinja2 or set global variable in jinja2 webapp2 python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, jinja2, webapp2

I am working on a webapp2 python project. Is there any way with which i can access the session variable in jinja2 templates. I know that we can get the session variable and then pass it to the template then we can use it. But i have alot of handlers and i do not want to pass the session variables each time to the render function. I am looking for something like we can do in php access direct session values in template. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use the BaseHandler to add template context:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """ webapp2 base handler """

    def __init__(self, request, response):

        self.session_store = None
        super(BaseHandler, self).__init__(request, response)
        user = users.get_current_user()
        # if not users.is_current_user_admin():
        if user.email() not in USER_CONFIG:
            self.abort(401)

    def dispatch(self):

        # Get a session store for this request.
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        if not self.session:
            session_data_or_default(self.session)
        try:
            # Dispatch the request.
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            self.session['route_name'] = self.request.route.name
            # Save all sessions.
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
        # we use memcache because the amount of data you can store in a secure cookie is limited.
        return self.session_store.get_session(name='my-secret-session', backend='memcache')

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(self, template, **template_args):
        template_args['session'] = self.session
        template_args['version'] = modules.get_current_version_name()

        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(template, **template_args))

    def return_rendered(self, template, **template_args):
        template_args['session'] = self.session

        return self.jinja2.render_template(template, **template_args)
```

Answer (score 3):

For webapp2 with Jinja2, it looks like you might need to use the [`webapp2_extras.jinja2.default_config`](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html#webapp2_extras.jinja2.default_config) and pass in additional globals. I think this is the correct syntax:

```
webapp2_extras.jinja2.default_config = {
  "globals": {
    "session": session
  }
}
```

And then in the template, you would access the session variables like this (assuming you set the "username" value):

```
<p>Welcome {{ session['username'] }}!</p>
```

Note: If you use Flask, which uses Jinja2 as the template engine, the session variables are passed as part of the [standard context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-context) to the templates.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit how can i use it?

Comment: Added usage example

Comment: it is giving error on session variable when we use it in the globals.